# Retornar o valor de dentro do execute_script selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

Olá, escrevi esse codigo aqui abaixo, e gostaria de retornar o valor do drive.execute_script. Eu sei que o valor é 3 do console.log(i), porem esse valor pode mudar, e quero retornar pra dentro do python, como faria isso?

````
```import time
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
import json

url = "https://shadowarena.pearlabyss.com/en-US/Arena?battleType=0&server=sa"
option = Options()
option.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script(''' 

const ranking = document.querySelectorAll('div.thum_name')

for(var i = 0; i < ranking.length; i++){
    var nick = document.querySelectorAll('div.thum_name')[i].innerText
    if(nick === "YoDaSL"){
        console.log(i)
    }

}
```


    ''')

time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
````

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas formas de você obter o valor do javascript para dentro do Python com o Selenium:

1) Alterar o Javascript para retornar o valor:

Exemplo:

```
output = driver.execute_script("return 30")
print(output)
=> 30
```

2) Para pegar do console.log(), você tem que habilitar o log do browser e pegar a resposta do log.
Exemplo:

```
# Habilitando o log no Firefox
d = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
d['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=d)
#driver.get(url)
driver.execute_script("console.log(30)")
# buscando todos os dados do log
for entry in driver.get_log('browser'):
    print(entry['message'])
=> 30 (:)
```

Espero ter ajudado.